# setup environment for running SQL queries in PowerShell 2.0 / 3.0

Tags: powershell

I would like to

a. Run SQL Queries using PowerShell and also manage the SQL Server. Can anyone please guide me on this?

b. Run AD Queries using PowerShell.

c. Please suggest location for SQL Server 2008 R2 or SQL Server 2008 PowerShell modules.
d. Is it sufficient enough for the host machine to run on PowerShell 3.0 and rest of the machine I am pulling the information to run on PS 2.0?

Any advice will be really helpful. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SQL queries, install the SQL Server Management Studio and along with it will come with [`SqlServerProviderSnapin100` and `SqlServerCmdletSnapin100`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2011/03/31/loading-sql-server-snapins-into-your-powershell-session.aspx). These 2 add-ins will give you most of what you need. For the rest, you'll need to use [SMO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2011/03/31/loading-sql-server-snapins-into-your-powershell-session.aspx).

AD queries - What you have available will depend greatly on what versions of Windows & Powershell you're running, as well as what you've installed. The RSAT tools give you some additional cmdlets IIRC, and then there's the [Quest AD cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx)(third-party) which simplify things a bit. Worst case, you end up doing a bunch of [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) queries

For your last question, it depends greatly on *how* you're pulling the information. In general, it will probably work fine, but if you're using PSRemoting and expecting a version 3 cmdlet to exist on the 2.0 system when you use a PSSession or`invoke-scriptblock`, it won't work. If a cmdlet lets you specify a `Computername` to connect to, it probably will work.

Comment: Thanks... Unfortunately my computer system runs on Windows XP! SQL Server Management Studio 2012 is only supported on Vista onwards. Sry, I should have mentioned this before. For AD queries, I got your point it depends on the version of the OS and Powershell. I had a look at Quest AD cmdlets, they seem to be quite helpful. If possible, please suggest on how to get SQL cmdlets on XP running PowerShell 2.0. Thanks

Comment: Install SSMS 2008 then. The cmdlets (and SMO) work across versions. Since you're on XP, the Quest AD cmdlets are your best bet for ease of use (vs. ADSI queries, etc.). But as timegoes on, if you're administrating Server 2008+, SQL Server 2008+, etc. remotely, you really need to get on a current OS to have all of the tools to get it done right. Even if it means having a server that you can remote into from your desktop to use those tools.